# Introductory Electricity and Magnetism Textbook for Biology and Biophysics

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, resource-recommendations, biophysics

My research advisor will be teaching a new course at my university on Electricity and Magnetism for Biophysics and Biology students. This is the first course the students would be taking in E&M. The course covers the following:

Coulomb's law, electric field, Gauss' law, potential, current, resistance, electromotive force, D.C. circuits, magnetic fields, induced electromotive forces; applications include cell membrane potentials, action potentials, role of charge in structure and function of DNA, basis for the magneto-encephalogram and biomedical instrumentations.

We cannot find an appropriate textbook, for this level since most biophysics textbooks are at the graduate level.